# What is the maximum number of addresses I can put into a LUT/ALT?

Tags: lookup-tables

Address of Lookup Tables allow us to store account addresses on-chain for "compressed" access inside transactions, but is there a limit to how many addresses can be stored in one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at [the docs](https://solana.com/docs/advanced/lookup-tables) says 256. Intuitively this makes sense too: In transactions, we refer to the position of addresses inside a LUT using a `u8` which can only store values from 0 to 255.